# Australian Tree Identification Help

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

[image]I am looking at identifying a tree for a friend who lives outside of Melbourne.  Being from Tennessee in the US, we don't have anything very similar to this at all and it doesn't look like any of the US tropical trees that I know of either.  Can anyone help?[image: This is the photo I got of the tree]

This is the far away view of the tree

Specific location: It was taken in the laneway behind a property in Glen Iris, Victoria just outside of Melbourne (Australia).

Comment: Also ask for how it smells.

Comment: The first 2 photos posted by Whitney show Syzygium paniculatum, or perhaps S.smithii. Magenta Cherry or Lilliplly.

Comment: Cat Mackenzie is right.
The leaves are darker, thinner, and more shiny than eucalyptus. The leaves also have two different sides, unlike eucalyptus.
Syzygium paniculatum, or S.smithii. I suspect S. smithii.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is more complicated than I first thought. I am pretty sure that we have an eukalyptus tree here. The species is more complicated, but I think it is likely *[Eucalyptus baueriana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_baueriana)* or one of its subspecies. To check this further, more detailed images of leaves, blossoms are needed. Check this image (from [here](http://www.trusttrees.org.au/tree/VIC/Werribee_South/Werribee_Park_Golf_Club_350_K_Road)):

[image]

Comment: It isn't the right species, the leaves in OP's picture are ovate but that of *E. viminalis* are lanceolate.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh You agree now?

Comment: I too think it is of that Genus, it is not my subject though. But looking at the leaves of E. baueriana, they are a little too ovate for OP's plant.

Comment: I think it is species E.ficifolia.

Comment: From the leaves, this could fit, but E. ficifolia has red blossoms, which the tree in the question has not.

Comment: Some variant of it has white flowers too.

Comment: Hey @Chris, your answer would be improved by providing further reasoning and support for why you think this is the correct species. You include a similar-looking image, but you don't really back up with any explicit characteristics or discussion for why your answer is correct. Please consider updating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume it is [*Corymbia ficifolia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corymbia_ficifolia) previously called Eucalyptus ficifolia, a white variant of this species which usually bears red flowers.

Image links:

[image][Source](https://gardeningwithhelen.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/e-ficifolia-feb.jpg)

- [Another picture](http://redwolfoz.deviantart.com/art/White-Flowering-Gum-Corymbia-ficifolia-582522115) (with a better view of the leaves)

Comment: Hey @TytoAlba, your answer would be improved by providing further reasoning and support for why you think this is the correct species. You include a similar-looking image, but you don't really back up with any explicit characteristics or discussion for why your answer is correct. Please consider updating. Thanks!